# Retrieve the attributes from a file using nodejs?

Tags: node.js

Hi I'm looking for an nodejs code which would probably return the attributes of each file in a folder. I developed the code to retrieve all the file name in a folder and another code to list data's of filename provide by us. But actually I need to return all the files names in a folder with its column name. I'm new to nodejs so someone help me please.

LISTING DATA CODE:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const neatCsv = require('neat-csv');

var s3 = new AWS.S3({});

exports.handler = (event,context,callback)=>{
const params = {
 Bucket:'ml-framework-api',
 Key: wavicle.csv
 };

 s3.getObject(params,async(err, result) => {
    if (err){
         return console.error(err);
     }
        
neatCsv(result.Body).then((parsedData) => {
    callback(null,parsedData);
})
})
}
```

LISTING FILE IN S3:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId:'-------------',
    secretAccessKey:'-------------------',
    region:'ap-south-1'
})

const params = {
    Bucket:'wavicle'
}

s3.listObjects(params,(err,data)=>{
    if(err){
        return console.log(err)
    }
    console.log(data)
})
```

Comment: Hi there, what code have you tried so far?

Comment: this code is for listing data                                                                                                                                           const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const neatCsv = require('neat-csv');

var s3 = new AWS.S3({});

exports.handler = (event,context,callback)=>{
const params = {
 Bucket:'ml-framework-api',
 Key: event['file']
 };

 s3.getObject(params,async(err, result) => {
    if (err){
         return console.error(err);
     }
        
neatCsv(result.Body).then((parsedData) => {
    callback(null,parsedData);
})
})
}

Comment: Hi there again, could you add that information to your question? Many people don't read the comments.

Comment: yeah added @Michelle

Answer (score 0):

It's best to start with node's [file system api documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_descriptors).

Here is a simple example of how to get information about files of a folder (there are many ways, this is quickly from the example in the documentation above):

```
const fsp = require("fs/promises");

async function dirFilesInfo(path) {
  const dir = await fsp.opendir(path);
  for await (const dirEntry of dir) {
    const fileInfo = await fsp.stat("./" + dirEntry.name);
    console.log(dirEntry.name, fileInfo);
  }
}
dirFilesInfo("./").catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Thanks for the code @Praym but I need the code to get column names of all files in a folder. Could please help me for that

Comment: What do you mean by "Column Name" of all files?